# strip error or no error

Tags: linux, shell, strip

I tried to strip a group of files with strip command in linux.
However I am getting the following error:

```
strip: files : could not create temporary file to hold stripped copy: No error
```

and then the command finished with no any other errors. Is there an error with the strip or no error? If there is error how do i fix it?

Comment: I have a directory with all the files i want to strip so i called: `strip *`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't seem to have permission to create files in the current working directory. Your user account needs write permissions on the directory for that.

Comment: ah that worked. Any idea why it showed as `No error` instead something like `Permission denied`?

Comment: @WilliamJia: The snarky answer would be "because that's how the authors wrote it", but that's not tremendously useful to you.